# Responsive text in <select> and align center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this `<select>` with `<option>`. I don't know why on desktop browser the text is centred and responsive, on mobile it's not centred...what can I do?

```
<p class="text-design col-xs-6 text-left orange-text">My line</p>
        <select class="select-category col-xs-6" name="">
            <option value="test"> Add</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

What your CSS code looks like?

You are using twitter bootstrap so you can use the `text-center` class, to align center :

`<select class="select-category col-xs-6 text-center" name="" >
            <option value="test"> Add</option>
        </select>`

[You can see the bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment)

Answer (score 0):

```
.text-left{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to center both the `<p></p>` and `<option></option>`. 
- It needs a padding inside the block of `<option>` to center it.
- It is a block element, and initially is set to padding:15px. 
I have implemented a codepen solution :) .
 http://codepen.io/aayusharora/pen/xggQmq